# UIImagePickerViewController is not responding to sourceType

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

The code that Iam using ,allows the application to run camera or photo library just once. I've implemented both these actions on an actionSheet using different indexes. The image is picked using Camera or Photo Library but just for the first time. Second time If the user tries using either of these action..the application crashes on this particular point: -

```
self.imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType;
```

What could be the reason? 
The method is which contains this code is as follows: -

```
- (void)setupImagePicker:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType {
    self.imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType;
    if (sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)
    {
        // user wants to use the camera interface
        self.imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;
        if ([[self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView subviews] count] == 0)
        {
            // setup our custom overlay view for the camera
            // ensure that our custom view's frame fits within the parent frame

            CGRect overlayViewFrame = self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView.frame;
            CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0.0,
                                         CGRectGetHeight(overlayViewFrame) -
                                         self.view.frame.size.height - 10.0,
                                         CGRectGetWidth(overlayViewFrame),
                                         self.view.frame.size.height + 10.0);
            self.view.frame = newFrame;
            [self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView addSubview:self.view];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use a variable `sourceType`? This is your culprit. Where and how are you creating the variable you are sending to this method?

Comment: @Mundi sourceType is method's parameter. It isn't declared anywhere else.

Comment: show the code you are using for creating and presenting the `imagePickerController` object.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `sourceType` that you are sending to your setup method is somehow corrupted the second time round.

In your program logic, make sure you call `setupImagePicker` with a correct parameter.

Answer (score 0):

check out this code

```
-(IBAction)TakePicture:(id)sender{

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]){
            self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        if([UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront ]){  
            self.picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront   ;
        }
    } else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Camera is not available for this Device" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
            self.takephoto.selected = NO;
        return;
    }


    self.picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
    self.picker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    self.picker.toolbarHidden = YES;
    self.picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
    self.picker.allowsEditing=YES;

    // Insert the overlay
    if (!self.overlay) {
        self.overlay = [[OverlayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OverlayViewController" bundle:nil];
    }
    self.overlay.pickerReference = self.picker;
    self.picker.cameraOverlayView = self.overlay.view;
    self.picker.delegate = self;

    [self presentModalViewController: self.picker animated:NO];

//    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];

}
```